# SQL query is very expensive

Tags: sql, sql-server, search

I have a query in SQL Server which searches for available service provider to book an appointment as following:

1. I have service provider related many to one with services table
2. Also service provider related many to one with staff members table
3. Services table related many to many with staffMember in StaffMemberService Table
4. I have appointmentDetails table related many to one with staffMember Table

You can see the details in this diagram:

[image]

The query is very expensive to find out what services has open time slots

```
--select * from ServiceProvider where Id > = 636 and CityId = 4 
DECLARE @longx      NVARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @laty       NVARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @userCityId INT;
DECLARE @userLocation GEOMETRY;
Declare @serviceName  NVARCHAR(50);
declare @startDate AS DATE;
declare @endDate   AS DATE;

SET @longx = '24.72977896594770';
SET @laty = '46.82470379239910';
SET @userCityId = 4;
SET @serviceName = '%hair%'
SET @userLocation = geometry::STPointFromText('POINT(' + @laty + ' ' + @longx + ')',0);
SET @startDate = '2019-06-01';
SET @endDate = '2019-06-05';

DECLARE @compareParts AS INT;
SET @compareParts = DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDate) * 40 ;

-- get all services like serviceName
-- find out which SP offer them
-- find out if sp has availble time in the specific dates 
WITH Serv AS
(
    SELECT s.* 
    FROM Services s 
    INNER JOIN ServiceProvider sp ON sp.Id = s.ServiceProviderId
    WHERE sp.CityId = @userCityId 
      AND s.Name LIKE @serviceName 
),
StaffServices AS
(
     SELECT s.* 
     FROM StaffMembers s 
     INNER JOIN StaffMemberService sms ON sms.StaffMemberId = s.Id
     INNER JOIN Serv ON sms.ServiceId = Serv.Id
),
StaffMemberAppointment AS
(
    SELECT ad.StaffMemberId, ad.Id, ad.Duration,a.ServiceProviderId 
    FROM AppointmentDetails ad 
    INNER JOIN Appointments a ON ad.AppointmentId = a.Id
    INNER JOIN ServiceProvider sp ON sp.Id = a.ServiceProviderId
    INNER JOIN StaffMemberService sms ON sms.StaffMemberId = ad.StaffMemberId
    INNER JOIN Serv ON Serv.Id = sms.ServiceId
    WHERE a.StartDt BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
),
appointmentParts AS
(
    SELECT 
        sa.StaffMemberId, sa.ServiceProviderId,  
        SUM(Datepart(minute, sa.duration) + DATEPART(hour, sa.duration) * 60 ) /15 AS appointmentsparts
    FROM
        StaffMemberAppointment sa
    GROUP BY
        sa.StaffMemberId, sa.ServiceProviderId
)
SELECT 
    sm.*,
    ap.appointmentsparts 
FROM
    StaffMembers sm
INNER JOIN
    StaffServices ss ON ss.Id = sm.Id
LEFT JOIN 
    appointmentParts ap ON sm.Id = ap.StaffMemberId
```

The basic idea I'm trying to look for services' name like a provided name, then I'm trying to find who are staff members can do the services and check how many already appointment time lots booked in a specific dates range then find the  service provider with the services.

The IO statistics a

```
(5 row(s) affected)
Table 'Appointments'. Scan count 0, logical reads 12, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'AppointmentDetails'. Scan count 5, logical reads 16, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ServiceProvider'. Scan count 0, logical reads 20, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'StaffMemberService'. Scan count 3, logical reads 28, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Services'. Scan count 6, logical reads 18, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'StaffMembers'. Scan count 0, logical reads 10, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)
```

time slot is 1 15 minutes. so the appointment with 30 minutes is 2 time slots.
I couldn't find a way to simplify this query, can any one help.

Comment: Did you look at the execution plan?

Comment: @DanielMann yes its big i could pasted her

Comment: You can past a plan using this site https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: @M.Kanarkowski Thanks : the plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Byiu8dg0E

Comment: The filtering predicate `AppointmentSlots < @maxSlots or AppointmentSlots is null` is being applied as the last step of the query making the whole query more expensive than necessary. I would move it to the most inner CTE you can, at least inside `appointmentParts`.

Comment: Also, how is it possible every cost in every node is 11%? Are you sure the plan is corrent?

Comment: @TheImpaler yes the plan is correct, i moved the filtering predicate into but there was no different

Answer (score 1):

What kind of execution plan do you get if you drop the CTE's and use a single level of join's with an OUTER APPLY to calculate the number of appointment slots?

```
SELECT  sm.Id, sm.Name, sm.ServiceProviderId, sp.Name, appt.AppointmentSlots
FROM    Services svc 
        INNER JOIN ServiceProvider sp ON sp.Id = svc.ServiceProviderId
        INNER JOIN StaffMemberService sms ON sms.ServiceId = svc.Id
        INNER JOIN StaffMembers sm ON sm.Id = sms.StaffMemberId
        OUTER APPLY 
        (
            SELECT  SUM( Datepart(minute, ad.duration) 
                        + Datepart(hour, ad.duration)*60 
                    ) / 15 AS AppointmentSlots
            FROM    Appointments a INNER JOIN AppointmentDetails ad 
                        ON  ad.AppointmentId = a.Id
            WHERE   a.ServiceProviderId = sp.ID 
            AND     ad.StaffMemberId = sms.StaffMemberId
            AND     a.StartDt between @startDate and @endDate
        ) appt
WHERE   sp.CityId = @userCityId 
AND     svc.Name like @serviceName 
AND (   AppointmentSlots < @maxSlots 
OR      AppointmentSlots IS NULL
    )
```

Comment: Also, aside from the PK's, what indexes exist on the appointment related tables?

Comment: it didnt gave the correct result, i need to aggregate the slots per staff member to decide if the staff member has an open appointments

Comment: i have created name index in Service, CityId in ServiceProvider, and startdt and endDt in appointment Table

Comment: ... and are you 100% sure the original query is calculating the totals *correctly*? I could be wrong, but ... it almost seems as if the appointment cte's are creating a CROSS JOIN - which would certainly explain why the query is slow/expensive...

Comment: In `AppointmentDetails`, there's no JOIN between `AppointmentDetails.ServiceId` and `Serv.Id` which would create a partial CROSS JOIN and cause the number of slots to be incorrect...